# NetGraph/Model for BERT?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Does anyone know of a way to get the BERT model working for word embeddings in Mathematica? Doesn’t seem to be available on GitHub or the Wolfram Net Repo...

Comment: Do you have any links or more details you could add to your question? The paper the model is specified in, for instance, or models built in other languages?

Comment: Well I just use pytorch to do this, but in general having proper tutorial on training transformer networks in mma would be great - a key paper is “all you need is attention” great read. But Bert is on the tf hub - that’s what I use.

Comment: If nothing else, here's [the link](https://github.com/google-research/bert) to the actual network mentioned, and here's [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805). Please add some more details to your post so that potential answerers don't need to do their own research before they can even start to try and help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Wolfram Language 12 is [just released](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/04/16/version-12-launches-today-big-jump-for-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/) so are the following new relevant models **compatible with it**. They were just added to the Wolfram Neural Network repository:

- [BERT Trained on BookCorpus and English Wikipedia Data](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/resourcesystem/published/NeuralNetRepository/resources/BERT-Trained-on-BookCorpus-and-English-Wikipedia-Data) - *Represent text as a sequence of vectors*
- [GPT Transformer Trained on BookCorpus Data](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/GPT-Transformer-Trained-on-BookCorpus-Data) - *Generate text in English and represent text as a sequence of vectors*

There are more updates in Neural Nets Repo that can be quickly scanned at:

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/all

There is more to come of course, stay tuned !